# Writing a matrix as a linear combination of matrices

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

Suppose I have two matrices `A` and `B`. After some calculations, I arrive at a matrix `M` and realize that `M` can be written as a linear combination of `A` and `B`,

```
M = a  A + b  B
```

for scalar constants `a` and `b`.

Is there a way to instruct Mathematica to express `M` as `a A + b B`?

In general, I am thinking of a function that takes a matrix `M` as an argument and explicitly writes it as a linear combination of a set of given matrices (in this case `A` and `B`).

Example:

```
A={{x,1},{0,y}};
B={{y^2,0},{x,2}}
```

From another calculation I have

```
M={{x+2y^2,1},{2x,y+4}};
```

I am looking for a function (or whatever can work) in Mathematica such that invoking `f[M]` produces:

```
A + 2*B
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

A = {{x, 1}, {0, y}};
B = {{y^2, 0}, {x, 2}};

M = {{x + 2 y^2, 1}, {2 x, y + 4}};

sol = Solve[
   Flatten[Thread /@ Thread[a*A + b*B == M]],
   {a, b}, {x, y}][[1]]

(* {a -> 1, b -> 2} *)
```

**EDIT:**  `Solve` can automatically `Thread`

```
sol = Solve[a*A + b*B == M, {a, b}, {x, y}][[1]]

(* {a -> 1, b -> 2} *)
```

Verifying,

```
a*A + b*B == M /. sol

(* True *)

HoldForm[a*A + b*B] /. sol
```

[image]

Comment: I need your help @Bob Hanlon for a numerical solution with Findroot

Comment: @Gallagher - post a question

Comment: Please @Bob Hanlon you can see my post https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/300202/58233

Comment: Please @Bob Hanlon: can you intervene in my post  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/300202/58233 to plot `Re[sol2]` and `Im[sol2]` for `0<k<20`. Thank you.

Comment: Can you intervene @Bob Hanlon in my post https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/300202/58233?

Comment: If I had anything to contribute I would have. Stop spamming me.