# Extract and solve complex solutions from ContourPlot/FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

I have to solve a complicated equation numerically `f(z,k)=0` with `z = x + i y` a complex variable and `k` a real, involving an integral of the inverse hyperbolic tangent function `ArcTanh`:

```
f[z_?NumericQ]:=1-k^2/z^2-5.811300019879834`*^7/k^2 NIntegrate[s Sqrt[s^2-1] (1-1/z-(s ((1-1/z)^2-(k^2 (s^2-1))/(s^2 z^2)) z ArcTanh[(k Sqrt[s^2-1])/(s (z-1))])/(k Sqrt[s^2-1]))Exp[-10 s],{s,1,Infinity},MaxRecursion->50,AccuracyGoal-> 1000]
```

However, `FindRoot` seems to be unable to find a solution for some values of `k`. But using `ContourPlot`, I can obtain a graph of the existing solutions within a few seconds:

```
$Version
"14.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)"

ClearAll["Global`*"]
(*k=0.01;*)

f[x_?NumericQ,y_?NumericQ]:=1-k^2/(x+I y)^2-5.811300019879834`*^7/k^2 NIntegrate[s Sqrt[s^2-1] (1-1/(x+I y)-(s ((1-1/(x+I y))^2-(k^2 (s^2-1))/(s^2 (x+I y)^2)) (x+I y) ArcTanh[(k Sqrt[s^2-1])/(s (x+I y-1))])/(k Sqrt[-1+s^2]))Exp[-10s],{s,1,Infinity},MaxRecursion->5,AccuracyGoal-> 1000]

ContourPlot[{Re@f[x,y]==0,Im@f[x,y]==0},{x,0,10},{y,-2,2},PlotPoints->20,FrameLabel->{TraditionalForm["x"],TraditionalForm["y"]},GridLines->Automatic]
```

The ContourPlot:

[image]

The above two ContourPlots show that there are two solutions of the equation in the complex plane, `sol1(k)` and `sol2(k)`, at the intersection of the curves `Re[f]=0` and `Im[f]=0`, but `sol2(k)` is too difficult to find with `FindRoot`.

So I have two questions to ask:

1. How to get/extract all `sol1(k)` and `sol2(k)` from ContourPlot without FindRoot?
2. `sol1` is easy to calculate by `FindRoot`, however `sol2` is difficult to obtain, in particular for `k>2` I get `sol2=sol1`, which is impossible, so how to compute and plot it for `0<k<20`?
   I specify that for all `k`, `Re[sol2]<1` and `Im[sol2]<0`.

   ```
   sol1[k_]:=z/. FindRoot[ 1-k^2/z^2-5.811300019879834`*^7/k^2 NIntegrate[s Sqrt[s^2-1](1-1/z-(s ((1-1/z)^2-(k^2 (s^2-1))/(s^2 z^2)) z ArcTanh[(k Sqrt[s^2-1])/(s (z-1))])/(k Sqrt[s^2-1]))Exp[-10 s],{s,1,Infinity},MaxRecursion->50,AccuracyGoal-> 1000]==0,{z,2+0.00001I},AccuracyGoal->5,MaxIterations->1000]

   Block[{k = 1.5}, {sol1[k], sol2[k]}]
   (*{5.220643413381576`-1.6472483643990675`*^-13 I,0.07822391435385899`+2.2735003026465596`*^-15 I}*)


   sol2[k_]:=z/. FindRoot[ 1-k^2/z^2-5.811300019879834`*^7/k^2 NIntegrate[s Sqrt[s^2-1](1-1/z-(s ((1-1/z)^2-(k^2 (s^2-1))/(s^2 z^2)) z ArcTanh[(k Sqrt[s^2-1])/(s (z-1))])/(k Sqrt[s^2-1]))Exp[-10 s],{s,1,Infinity},MaxRecursion->50,AccuracyGoal-> 1000]==0,{z,0.0001-0.000001 I},AccuracyGoal->5,MaxIterations->1000]

   Block[{k = 2}, {sol1[k], sol2[k]}]
   (*{5.382348544051253`-2.5539453851686417`*^-12 I,5.38234854405347`-4.1359030627651384`*^-23 I}*)
   ```

Comment: Good luck!  Complex root finding is really hard and requires magic. In the past, I've used Mathematica to find the intersections between the zero-contours of the real and imaginary parts using Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[plot], then feeding the results to `FindRoot` to refine the roots. It doesn't seem to work for your difficult points, though.

Comment: Thank you @march for the comment.

Answer (score 4):

To select points `Sol1,Sol2` we use `Select` at points extracting from `ContourPlot` as follows

```
f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
 1 - k^2/(x + I  y)^2 - 
  5.811300019879834`*^7/k^2  NIntegrate[
    s  Sqrt[s^2 - 1]  (1 - 
       1/(x + I  y) - (s  ((1 - 
               1/(x + I  y))^2 - (k^2  (s^2 - 
                 1))/(s^2  (x + I  y)^2))  (x + 
            I  y)  ArcTanh[(k  Sqrt[
               s^2 - 1])/(s  (x + I  y - 1))])/(k  Sqrt[-1 + 
            s^2])) Exp[-10 s], {s, 1, Infinity}]

plot = Table[
  ContourPlot[{Re@f[x, y] == 0, Im@f[x, y] == 0}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, -2, 
    2}, PlotPoints -> 20, 
   FrameLabel -> {TraditionalForm["x"], TraditionalForm["y"]}, 
   GridLines -> Automatic], {k, {.01, 3}}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

To extract points from plot we use

```
point1 = plot[[1]][[1, 1]][[1]];

point2 = plot[[2]][[1, 1]][[1]];
```

Visualization

```
{ListPlot[point1], ListPlot[point2]}
```

[image: Figure 2]
There are 3 branches in every plot, and we need one of them

```
b11 = plot[[1]][[1, 1]][[2, 1, 3]][[1]][[2]][[1]];
```

Visualization

```
ListPlot[point1[[b11]]]
```

[image: Figure 3]

To select roots from points above we use

```
root = Select[point1[[b11]], Abs[#[[2]]] < 10^-6 &]

(*Out[]= {{5.0054, -1.11022*10^-16}, {1.04057, -1.11022*10^-16}}*)
```

Visualization

```
Show[ListPlot[point1[[b11]]], 
 ListPlot[root, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Figure 4]

Same steps for `plot[[2]]`

```
b21 = plot[[2]][[1, 1]][[2, 1, 3]][[1]][[2]][[1]];

root2 = Select[point2[[b21]], Abs[#[[2]]] < 10^-6 &]

(*Out[]= {{0.0328947, -1.11022*10^-16}, {5.82164, -1.11022*10^-16}}*)

Show[ListPlot[point2[[b21]]], 
 ListPlot[root2, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Figure 5]

Note, that roots extracted from `ContourPlot` data are very rough. Nevertheless we can plot `Sol2` as function of `k` as follows

```
f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
 1 - k^2/(x + I y)^2 - 
  5.811300019879834`*^7/k^2 NIntegrate[
    s Sqrt[s^2 - 1] (1 - 
       1/(x + I y) - (s ((1 - 
               1/(x + I y))^2 - (k^2 (s^2 - 
                 1))/(s^2 (x + I y)^2)) (x + 
            I y) ArcTanh[(k Sqrt[
               s^2 - 1])/(s (x + I y - 1))])/(k Sqrt[-1 + 
            s^2])) Exp[-10 s], {s, 1, Infinity}]

plot = Table[
   ContourPlot[{Re@f[x, y] == 0, Im@f[x, y] == 0}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, -2,
      2}, PlotPoints -> 20, 
    FrameLabel -> {TraditionalForm["x"], TraditionalForm["y"]}, 
    GridLines -> Automatic], {k, Range[.01, 4.01, .25]}];

point = Table[plot[[i]][[1, 1]][[1]], {i, Length[plot]}];
b = Table[
   plot[[i]][[1, 1]][[2, 1, 3]][[1]][[2]][[1]], {i, Length[plot]}];
root = Flatten[
  Table[MinimalBy[Select[point[[i]][[b[[i]]]], Abs[#[[2]]] < 10^-6 &],
     First], {i, Length[plot]}], 1];
kr = Range[2, 3, .1]; plot1 = 
 Table[ContourPlot[{Re@f[x, y] == 0, Im@f[x, y] == 0}, {x, 0, 
    10}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 20, 
   FrameLabel -> {TraditionalForm["x"], TraditionalForm["y"]}, 
   GridLines -> Automatic], {k, kr}];

point1 = Table[plot1[[i]][[1, 1]][[1]], {i, Length[plot1]}];
b1 = Table[
   plot1[[i]][[1, 1]][[2, 1, 3]][[1]][[2]][[1]], {i, Length[plot1]}];
 root1 = Flatten[
  Table[MinimalBy[
    Select[point1[[i]][[b[[i]]]], Abs[#[[2]]] < 10^-6 &], First], {i, 
    Length[plot1]}], 1];
```

Visualization `Re[Sol2[k]]`

```
ListPlot[
 Transpose[{Join[Range[.01, 4.01, .25], kr], 
   Join[root[[All, 1]], root1[[All, 1]]]}]]
```

[image: Figure6]

Update 1.We can map infinite interval in `NIntegrate` on the unit interval $(0,1)$ using substitution $s\rightarrow 1/u$. With this substitution we define new function

```
ftest[k_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
 1 - k^2/(z)^2 - 
  Rationalize[5.811300019879834`*^7, 30]/(k^3 z) NIntegrate[(
    E^(-10/u) (k Sqrt[
        1 - u^2] (-1 + z) - (k^2 (-1 + u^2) + (-1 + z)^2) ArcTanh[(
         k Sqrt[1 - u^2])/(-1 + z)]))/u^4, {u, 0, 1}]
```

In test example function `ftest` generates same results as `f`, but about 8 times faster

```
ftest[1, 1/2] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[]= {0.0086506, 104.563 - 33.2089 I}
```

Using `ftest` we can produce this plot

```
ContourPlot[{Re[ftest[1, x + I y]] == 0, 
   Im[ftest[1, x + I y]] == 0}, {x, .0, .1}, {y, -.1, .1}, 
  PlotPoints -> 25]
```

[image: Figure 7]

As we can see there is small root `Sol2` that we lost in the large scale plot above. Now we can use `FindRoot` to compute `Sol2[k]` as follows

```
 roots = 


Table[{k, 
   z /. Quiet@
     FindRoot[ftest[k, z] == 0, {z, .000001, .001}, 
      Method -> "Secant"]}, {k, .15, .95, .1}]

Out[]= {{0.15, 0.0011195}, {0.25, 0.00309493}, {0.35, 
  0.0060224}, {0.45, 0.00985867}, {0.55, 0.0145452}, {0.65, 
  0.0200069}, {0.75, 0.02615}, {0.85, 0.0328578}, {0.95, 0.0399814}}
```

We can test quality of this roots as

```
ftest[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ roots

Out[]= {5.49335*10^-10, -2.29284*10^-9, -2.50111*10^-11, 
 2.72848*10^-12, -7.13953*10^-11, -3.53111*10^-10, -1.4677*10^-10, \
-8.29914*10^-12, -1.13687*10^-13}
```

Therefore in this interval we have next plot

```
ListLinePlot[Re[roots], AxesLabel -> {"k", "Re(Sol2)"}]
```

[image: Figure 8]

For small `k<0.15`we can compute roots with `Solve` using series

```
Series[(E^(-10/
     u) (k Sqrt[
       1 - u^2] (-1 + z) - (k^2 (-1 + u^2) + (-1 + z)^2) ArcTanh[(
        k Sqrt[1 - u^2])/(-1 + z)]))/u^4, {k, 0, 3}] // Normal

Out[]= -((2 E^(-10/u) k^3 Sqrt[1 - u^2] (-1 + u^2))/(3 u^4 (-1 + z))
```

Therefore `ftest` has an asymptotic at `k<<1` in the form

```
fs = 
 1 - k^2/(z)^2 - Rationalize[c  5.811300019879834`*^7, 30]/( z (z - 1))

Out[]= 1 - k^2/z^2 - 20/((-1 + z) z)
```

Where

```
c = NIntegrate[-((2  E^(-10/u)   Sqrt[1 - u^2]  (-1 + u^2))/(
   3  (u^4) )), {u, 0, 1}]

Out[]= 3.44925*10^-7
```

With this asymptotic we solve roots `exactly` using `Solve`

```
Z = z /. Solve[fs == 0, z]

Out[]= {1/3 - (-61 - 3 k^2)/(
  3 (91 - 9 k^2 + 3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[-8100 - 1301 k^2 - 58 k^4 - k^6])^(
   1/3)) + 1/
   3 (91 - 9 k^2 + 3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[-8100 - 1301 k^2 - 58 k^4 - k^6])^(
   1/3), 1/3 + ((1 + I Sqrt[3]) (-61 - 3 k^2))/(
  6 (91 - 9 k^2 + 3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[-8100 - 1301 k^2 - 58 k^4 - k^6])^(
   1/3)) - 1/
   6 (1 - I Sqrt[3]) (91 - 9 k^2 + 
     3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[-8100 - 1301 k^2 - 58 k^4 - k^6])^(1/3), 
 1/3 + ((1 - I Sqrt[3]) (-61 - 3 k^2))/(
  6 (91 - 9 k^2 + 3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[-8100 - 1301 k^2 - 58 k^4 - k^6])^(
   1/3)) - 1/
   6 (1 + I Sqrt[3]) (91 - 9 k^2 + 
     3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[-8100 - 1301 k^2 - 58 k^4 - k^6])^(1/3)}
```

Visualization

```
Table[Plot[Evaluate[ReIm@Z[[i]]], {k, 0, .15}], {i, Length[Z]}]
```

[image: Figure 9]

Note, that last plot corresponds to `roots` computed above with `FindRoot`. Therefore we can test asymptotic at `k=0.15`

```
Z[[3]] /. k -> .15

Out[]= 0.00112367 + 1.33227*10^-15 I
```

And with `FindRoot` we have `0.0011195038138796902`. This asymptotic working nice up to `k=0.75` as shown below

```
Show[Plot[Re@Z[[3]], {k, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"k", "Re(Sol2)"}], 
 ListPlot[roots, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Figure 10]

**Update 2**. We also can compute asymptotic formula at `k>>1` as follows

```
Series[(E^(-10/
     u) (k Sqrt[
       1 - u^2] (-1 + z) - (k^2 (-1 + u^2) + (-1 + z)^2) ArcTanh[(
        k Sqrt[1 - u^2])/(-1 + z)]))/(u^4 k^3), {k, Infinity, 3}] // 
  Normal

Out[]= -((2 E^(-10/u) (-1 + u^2) (-1 + z))/(
  k^2 u^4 Sqrt[1 - u^2])) + (
 E^(-10/u) \[Pi] (-1 + u^2) Sqrt[(
  k^2 (-1 + u^2))/(-1 + z)^2] (-1 + z))/(2 k^2 u^4 Sqrt[1 - u^2]) + (
 E^(-10/u) \[Pi] Sqrt[(k^2 (-1 + u^2))/(-1 + z)^2] (-1 + z)^3)/(
 2 k^4 u^4 Sqrt[1 - u^2])
```

Therefore `ftest` has an asymptotic at k>>1` in a form

```
fl = 
 1 - k^2/(z)^2 - 
  Rationalize[Expand[5.811300019879834`*^7 (c1 + c2 + c3)], 30]/( z)


Out[]= 1 - k^2/z^2 - ((505 I)/k^3 - 250/k^2 - (91 I)/k - (1011 I z)/
  k^3 + (250 z)/k^2 + (505 I z^2)/k^3)/z
```

Where

```
c1 = (-1 + z)/
   k^2  NIntegrate[-((2 (E^(-10/u)) (-1 + u^2) )/( 
    u^4  Sqrt[1 - u^2])), {u, 0, 1}]

Out[]= (4.30196*10^-6 (-1 + z))/k^2



c2 = 
 1/k  NIntegrate[((E^(-10/u)) \[Pi]  (-1 + u^2)  Sqrt[(-1 + u^2)] )/(
   2   u^4  Sqrt[1 - u^2]), {u, 0, 1}]

Out[]= -((0. + 1.56891*10^-6 I)/k)



c3 = (-1 + z)^2/
   k^3  NIntegrate[((E^(-10/u))  \[Pi]  Sqrt[(-1 + u^2)] )/(
   2  u^4  Sqrt[1 - u^2]), {u, 0, 1}]

Out[]= ((0. + 8.70031*10^-6 I)  (-1 + z)^2)/k^3
```

Finally we solve and plot roots at `k>2`

```
ZZ = z /. Solve[fl == 0, z];
Table[Plot[Evaluate[ReIm@ZZ[[i]]], {k, 2, 20}], {i, Length[ZZ]}]
```

[image: Figure 11]

Comment: Thank you @Alex Trounev so much for the answer, please for question 2, how to plot all   `Re[Sol2(k)]` and `Im[Sol2]` versus `k`
 for  `0<k<20` ? Many thanks.

Comment: @Gallagher We don't need large range. At `k>3` all roots are same `{0.0328947, -1.11022*10^-16}`.

Comment: How to plot these Re and Im roots please?

Comment: @Gallagher: How precise must these roots be? Extracting roots from plots is not very precise. The left roots are quite off in both cases. Try to substitute them in the original function.

Comment: @Alex `ContourPlot` gives only two roots for a given `k`, please how to plot from selected roots all roots `Re[Sol2(k)]` and `Im[Sol2(k)]`  for `0<k<20`?

Comment: @Gallagher Please see update to my answer.

Comment: @Alex: thank you so much, but I can't see the plot well, can you improve it please? A precision, for `k<<1` Sol2 verifies `Re[Sol2]<<<1`  and not greater than 1.

Comment: @Gallagher It takes a time to compute data. Could you also try to improve this solution?

Comment: @Alex Trounev: the roots ``Re[Sol2(k)]`` that you plotted do not seem to be the correct results, because they must be all less than 1, ``Re[Sol2(k)]<<1``. I think that using ``FindRoot`` is better but I can't do it.

Comment: @Gallagher  How you know this estimation `Re[Sol2(k)]<<1`? From my solution it follows, that  `Im[Sol2(k)]<<1`.

Comment: @Alex Trounev ``Re[Sol2(k)]<<1`` from ``ContourPlot`` for various ``k``. You can check it for ``k<<1``.

Comment: @Gallagher You are right, see Update 1 to my answer.

Comment: @Alex Trounev, thank you so much for your remarkable answers. You did everything correctly, I am grateful to you. But there is still a problem to solve that I can't understand. For ``k=<1.8`` the roots ``Re[Sol2(k)]`` obtained by ``FindRoot[ftest[k, z] == 0]`` are good ``<<1``, however for ``k>1.8`` FindRoot gives the same false value, i.e. ``Sol2(1.9)=Sol2(2)=Sol2(2.5)=5,.....``. Maybe the precision? Do you have an idea please?

Comment: @Alex Trounev, in update 1, when you replace `s` with `1/u` to get the new function `ftest`, I think you are missing a **minus sign** in the integrand of `ftest`, which comes from the differential `ds=(-1/u²)du`, can you check it please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151957/discussion-between-gallagher-and-alex-trounev).

Comment: No, sign is on since limits of integral also should be swapped. Actually I tested `ftest` compare to `f`, they show same result, but `ftest` is faster.

Comment: @Alex Trounev it's still the same problem that I can't solve. For `k=<1.9` all the roots `Re[Sol2(k)]` obtained by `FindRoot[ftest[k, z] == 0]` are good <<1 and correspond perfectly to the roots found by `ContourPlot`, however for `k>1.9` `FindRoot` gives false values different from those calculated by `ContouPlot`, look for example `Re[Sol2(2)]=5.38` by `FindRoot` while `Re[Sol2(2)]=0.137` by `ContouPlot`, this is the crucial problem of this post. Perhaps the precision? Do you have an idea please?

Comment: @Gallagher I don't think that we can solve this problem without mathematical research. Your first question about data retrieved from `ContourPlot` has an answer. But your second question and problem you try to solve is not clear. Maybe we need redefine `ArcTanh[]`  to get unique solution, since algorithm implemented in Mathematica is not so advanced to solve this problem. Could you start a new topic with your problem explanation?

Comment: @Alex Trounev maybe there is no solutions `Sol2` for `k>2` ?

Comment: @Gallagher This is a good question. Answer depends on what you are looking for. It seems that you try to compute integral of singular function in complex plain. Is it correct?

Comment: @Alex Trounev,  Yes exactly.

Comment: Let try this function `ftest1[k_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
 1 - k^2/(z)^2 - 
  Rationalize[5.811300019879834`*^7, 
     30]/(k^3  z)  NIntegrate[(E^(-10/
          u)  (k  Sqrt[
           1 - u^2]  (-1 + 
            z) - (k^2  (-1 + u^2) + (-1 + z)^2)  ArcTanh[(k  Sqrt[
               1 - u^2])/(-1 + z)]))/u^4, {u, 0, 0, 1}, 
    Method -> "PrincipalValue"]`

Answer (score 2):

`ArcTanh[w]` has branch cuts for `Abs[w] > 1 && Im[w] == 0`.  As shown in Alex Trounev's answer, the function presented in the question can be rewritten as `ftest`, which contains `ArcTanh[(k Sqrt[1 - u^2])/(-1 + z)]` with `u` ranging over `{0, 1}`.  Thus, the branch cuts in `ArcTanh` impact the integral for `Abs[k/(-1 + z)] > 1 && Im[z] == 0`.  This can be visualized by

```
RegionPlot[Abs[k/(1 - z)] > 1, {z, 0, 4}, {k, 0, 4}, 
    FrameLabel -> {z, k}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

indicating that special care should be taken for real `z` in the shaded area.  To make this more concrete, consider results for `k = 0.5`, for which the branch cuts could interfere with results for `0.5 < z < 1.5`.  The corresponding `ContourPlot` is

```
ContourPlot[{Re@ftest[.5, x + I  y] == 0, Im@ftest[.5, x + I  y] == 0}, 
    {x, 0, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, GridLines -> Automatic, FrameLabel -> {x, y}, 
    LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

shows `y = 0` as a solution to `Im@ftest[.5, x + I y] == 0`, although the plot looks a bit irregular for `0.6 < x < 1.4`.  Next, plot

```
ReImPlot[ftest[.5, 1.2 + I y], {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All, 
    AxesLabel -> {y, f}, ReImStyle -> {Automatic, Dashing[{0.03, 0.01}]},
    LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

Similar plots in `y` for other values of `0.5 < x < 1.5` show similar discontinuities at `y = 0`, although the discontinuities are much smaller for `x` at the ends of the range just given. Outside this range, such plots show no discontinuities.

Next, consider plots of constant `y` very near `y = 0`.

```
p2 = ReImPlot[ftest[.5, x + 0.0001*I], {x, 0, 2}, AxesLabel -> {x, f}, 
    PlotStyle -> Red, ReImStyle -> {Automatic, Dashing[{0.03, 0.01}]}, 
    LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Black}];
p3 = ReImPlot[ftest[.5, x - 0.0001*I], {x, 0, 2}, AxesLabel -> {x, f}, 
    PlotStyle -> Red, ReImStyle -> {Automatic, Dashing[{0.03, 0.01}]}, 
    LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Black}];
p1 = ReImPlot[ftest[.5, x + 0.0001*I], {x, 0, 2}, AxesLabel -> {x, f}, 
    ReImStyle -> {Automatic, Dashing[{0.03, 0.01}]}, 
    LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Black}];
Show[p2, p3, p1]
```

[image]

Larger values of constant `y` show similar behavior for `0.5 < x < 1.5`.  Thus, `y == 0` clearly is not a solution to `Im@ftest[.5, x + I  y] == 0`, contrary to the impression given by the `ContourPlot`.  Perhaps, it is confused by the discontinuities there.  All this indicates that solutions to the question lying in the shaded area of the first plot here should not be trusted.  Applying this to Alex Tournev's answer suggests that the "Sol1" solutions are correct, but the "Sol2" solutions are incorrect.  The solutions for small `z` given in his update also appear to be correct.

Comment: It's very clear @bbgodfrey, thank you so much for these details and explanations on branch cuts. Hoping they provide something to resolve this issue. But I have a question, maybe I'm wrong, you say at the end that _Alex Tournev's answer suggests that `Sol2` solutions are correct, but `Sol1` solutions are incorrect_, `Sol1` is correct, right?

Comment: @Gallagher Thank you for catching my misstatement.  Sol1 solutions are correct, but Sol2 solutions are incorrect.